# XML to treeview based on ParentId

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, vb.net

I have an XML like this:

```
<table name="tblcats">
<row>
        <Id>1741</Id>
        <Industry>Oil &amp; Gas - Integrated</Industry>
        <ParentId>1691</ParentId>
    </row>
    <row>
        <Id>1690</Id>
        <Industry>Commodities</Industry>
        <ParentId>1691</ParentId>
    </row>
    <row>
        <Id>1691</Id>
        <Industry>Capital Goods</Industry>
        <ParentId>0</ParentId>
    </row>
</table>
```

I want to create a Treeview from this XML so that table is parent node and then nodes ParentId 0 is second parent and then child nodes with Parent Id greater than 0

Like this:

+Table
    +Capital Goods
       Commodities
       Oil & Gas - Integrated

How can I do this? Please suggest

Regards,
Asif Hameed

Answer (score 1):

A fairly simplistic approach would be to use the standard ASP.NET controls XmlDataSource and TreeView and use an XSLT transform file to transform the XML you have into something that the TreeView control likes.

So, assuming you have the XML above in a file called cats.xml, the ASP.NET page markup would look like:

```
<asp:XmlDataSource ID="CatsXml" runat="server" DataFile="~/cats.xml" TransformFile="~/cats.xslt"></asp:XmlDataSource>
<asp:TreeView ID="CatsTree" runat="server" DataSourceID="CatsXml">
    <DataBindings><asp:TreeNodeBinding TextField="name" ValueField="id" /></DataBindings>
</asp:TreeView>
```

and the XSLT file (cats.xslt) would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="table">
    <table id="-1" name="Table">
      <xsl:for-each select="/table/row[ParentId = 0]">
        <industry>
          <xsl:attribute name="id">
            <xsl:value-of select="Id"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:attribute name="name">
            <xsl:value-of select="Industry"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:call-template name="industry-template">
            <xsl:with-param name="pId" select="Id" />
          </xsl:call-template>
        </industry>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="industry-template">
    <xsl:param name="pId" />
    <xsl:for-each select="/table/row[ParentId = $pId]">
      <industry>
        <xsl:attribute name="id">
          <xsl:value-of select="Id"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="name">
          <xsl:value-of select="Industry"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:call-template name="industry-template">
          <xsl:with-param name="pId" select="Id" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </industry>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Stuart.